# How to uninstall helix-editor completely along with all helix related files and configurations?

Tags: debian, editors, uninstall, rust

The steps here are NOT clear to me. I am using Debian

https://github.com/helix-editor/helix/discussions/5228

Installation steps:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/helix-editor/helix

~/helix ‹master› $ cargo install --path helix-term --locked
```

**Can some one guide me in simple steps, please?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the folder containing the repository and run `cargo uninstall`. If you are unsure where you have cloned the repository to, you can run `find ~/ -type d -name "helix"` assuming you cloned the repo into your home folder, If it's not found remove the `~` from the find command.

Also run `rm -r ~/.config/helix` to delete the configuration files.

Update based on your comment:

Open your terminal and write `cd ~/helix` and then run `cargo uninstall`

Next execute `rm -r ~/helix ~/.cache/helix` and you should be good.

Comment: Sir: Thank you for your help: I searched and found :$ sudo find ~/ -type d -name "helix"                                                                                            
/home/me/helix
/home/me/helix/runtime/grammars/sources/cpon/queries/helix
/home/me/.cache/helix
/home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/helix.2/runtime/grammars/sources/cpon/queries/helix
/home/me/.local/share/Trash/files/helix
find: ‘/run/user/1000/doc’: Permission denied
find: ‘/run/user/1000/gvfs’: Permission denied. Tried from home Dir $ cargo uninstall helix. But, it did not work

Comment: You are welcome. So, from the output of your find command, I can tell that you have cloned the helix git repo into your home folder. See my updated answer for the step-by-step guide.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind responses. I tried all those but it is not working. So, I re-installed debiin, and trying to download pre-built AppImage.

Comment: *I tried all those but it is not working* but they should. Very likely you did something wrong. Now there's no point in telling to re-do the steps while paying attention for typos and/or other mistakes but you should accept the answer anyway.

Comment: ChanganAuto: Done!